# Runtime manipulation of ListView

Tags: android

developers.

I would like to ask for help for a task. Unfortunately, I can not upload any code because I do not know how to get started.

I would need to create a listview where I can check the views of all its appearing elements while scrolling and ask to change the view while scrolling.

Specifically: The list item displayed in the center of the screen should be larger than the others, and as I scroll the list up or down, the letters become smaller.

It would look like a scroll on a cylinder.

I would like to ask for help on this problem.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out this Github Page : [CarouselLayoutManager](https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager)
Its got instructions and examples..

Comment: Thanks, this is good, but I do not need this. It works with fixed sizes and I would like to write it down, if it can be simpler. Is there any other idea?